# Render chart in bootstrap modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chart js to load the chart in my html page. I have created the chart successfully and showing in my canvas. Now I want to load that chart html into my popup using jquery on some button click.

I wrote the code as ---

```
window.showChartPopup = function(title,id){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#chartPopupModal").find('#chart-title').html(title);
    $("#chartPopupModal").find('#chart-content').html($("#"+id).html());
    $("#chartPopupModal").modal('show');
}
```

I am calling showChartPopup function on the button click with passing some title and the id of that div which is outer div of the canvas in my html page.
but this code showing me the popup with no chart showing on it..

can any one help me how can render the chart html into my modal as I want one modal to all charts in my single page so that i can load each chart in my modal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more code ?

Comment: Swati other code is just to show the chart. just chart.js code in my html not in popup